# Count Comparisons for Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, counter

I'm trying to count the number of comparisons a merge sort algorithm makes when sorting a list. I've tried multiple ways, but due to the recursion, I am always returned with an answer that is essentially the size of the list. Any suggestion on how to count the number of comparisons this makes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1. less beautiful, but easier to implement.

Declare counter as global variable. You can refer to it in your function by using `global counter`.

2. Avoiding global variables

Here:

```
mergesort(lefthalf)
mergesort(righthalf)
```

You do not make use of the returned comparison counter. if you make something like:

```
count += mergesort(lefthalf)
count += mergesort(righthalf)
```

You will get your comparison count. Remember to initialize your counter with 0 each time you call `mergesort()`